# Deleting duplicates in the array

Tags: c, arrays

I made a program to delete duplicates in an array but the program's if condition always remain true.
I understood what the problem was,changed arr[i] to arr[count] and allocated memory via malloc,but the program prints the array as it is without deleting the duplicates.

```
    # include<stdio.h>
    # include<stdlib.h>
    int count=0;
    void Delete(int *arr);
    void Search(int *arr);

    int main()
    {
    int i;
    int *arr;
    arr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter array and press -1 to stop:\n");/*stops when -1 occurs*/
    for(count=0;    ;count++)/*count is the count of the numbers*/
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[count]);
        realloc(arr,sizeof((int)+count));
        fflush(stdin);
        if(*(arr+count)==-1)/*This condition is never true.*/
        break;
    }
    Search(arr);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

    Search(arr);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this: if(*(arr+count)==-1) - why not use arr[count] == -1? Your code is littered with this...

Comment: change scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 to scanf("%d",&arr[count]);
edit: btw this is homework, isnt it?

Comment: Keeping the array length in a global variable, `count`, is iffy..

Comment: Though the question is for C, there might be no harm in looking at `unique` for ideas http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/unique/

Comment: @Thomas O:Does that makes a diffrence?

Comment: `realloc(arr,sizeof((int)+count))` should read `realloc(arr,sizeof(int)+count)`.

Comment: @fahad: It only suffices to make the code (more) unreadable.

Comment: @Arun:Do you have a better idea than making it global?

Comment: @fahad: I would make the `count` a local variable where the array is constructed, e.g. `main()`, and then **pass** it (e.g. as a second argument) to all the routines (e.g. `Search()`, `Delete()`) that need to work on the array.

Comment: @Arun:that would have made no diffrence I guess,we both end up to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates from array create a method, that:

- sorts the array
- counts unique values
- creates a new array, that is of size unique values
- start coping from 1 array to the other, when their values are different

To use quicksort in c, you need comparator function like:

```
int comp(const void *x, const void *y) {
  return (*(int*)x - *(int*)y);
}
```

And then you can call it with:

```
qsort(array, 10, sizeof(int), comp);
```

To count unique items in sorted array, iterate over the array, and do something like:

```
if(sortedarray[i]!=sortedarray[i+1]) count++;
```

Comment: I tried to search the array,find a duplicate and perform deletion on it.

Comment: @fahad That is very in effective! If you where using a linked list that would be a good idea, but not with an array.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized arr. Currently it's just a pointer, it has no actual bound on it, so you could be overwriting something else.

Also, you're never incrementing 
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
I think you want that to read         scanf("%d",&arr[counter]);

Comment: Thankyou,how would i allocate memory if  I dont know how many numbers will the user enter?Should i allocate some memory and increment it with realloc for each iteration?